# cannot uninstall node and npm completely on high sierra

Tags: node.js, macos

I recently installed **Node** on my MacBook running `High Sierra 10.13` using the `.pkg` file supplied on their website.

After a few hours of experimenting with installing other packages and writing scripts, I decided I would like to uninstall both Node **and** NPM to get a fresh start.
I tried all of the top answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) thread, but to my dismay, after having followed all instructions, and repeated all steps many times, terminal would still recognise the Node and NPM versions.

I ended up running a `bash` script through terminal which I found on the same thread, which ended up doing nothing but downgrading my current version of Node to `0.10.8` - making it a lot more difficult to delete in the long run.

I've re-done all of the steps from the aforementioned thread with no avail, and terminal still stating that it has version `0.10.8` (and **NPM** just completely not working at all)

Currently at my last stance of what to do, so hopefully someone on here can help me with my problem.

Cheers.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it how to completely remove node and re-install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching through `Google` and `StackOverflow` for hours, I finally came up with a solution to the problem on my own. 

Running the `type` command within **terminal** against `node`, I got this returned:

```
:~ myusername$ type node
node is /Users/myusername/.nvm/v0.10.48/bin/node
```

Subsequently, after deleting that folder, Node appears to be completely removed from my system.

---

I have since made sure that I have deleted all `node` and `node_module` folders that I could find within `/usr/` to make sure - and I would suggest that anyone attempting this also do the same.

Comment: thanks! type node turned up /usr/local/opt/heroku-node/bin/node which must have been installed with the heroku cli!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command

```
brew uninstall node
```

After the above command, you need to scan manually for node_modules if exists. Try following.

```
grep -irl "node_modules/node"

sudo rm -rf result_from_above_command
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

I hope this will remove all the node and it's components. As I have done like this, once before.
Thank you.

Comment: I didn't use brew to install node, so this won't work. Sorry mate

Comment: Terminal hanged by showing this warning: grep: warning: recursive search of stdin